# FindsBy attribute with resource file c# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Using PageObject pattern in selenium and i would like to put all the locators in  a resource file.

wondering if possible to use a FindsBy Attribute with resource file

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "btnUserApply")]
public Button ApplyButton { get; set; }
```

becomes as below which gives an error and cannot be done

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = MyRexFile.btnUserApply)]
 public Button ApplyButton { get; set; }
```

FindsBy is also sealed so cannot inherit .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible. `FindsBy` annotation receives const (evaluated in compilation) string as the `Using` parameter. Data from resource file is evaluated in run time.

You could create another class to hold all the locators

```
public static class Locators
{
    public const string btnUserApply = "btnUserApply";
}

public class PageObject
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = Locators.btnUserApply)]
    public Button ApplyButton { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are you saying it works only with constants? what about creating your own  custom FindsBy that accept attributes .there is no much on the web about this

Comment: @developer9969 Yes, `FindsBy` works only with constants. I never tried to create custom `FindsBy` nor encountered such attempt. But maybe it is possible.